# Cannot read excel sheet with specific year. Returns overflow error

Tags: python, pandas, excel

The following code allows me to load the latest spreadsheet named 2023.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(filepath, storage_options={:})

# Define an empty list to store individual dataframes
list_of_dfs = []

# Iterate through each worksheet
for sheet in xl.sheet_names[12:13]:
    df = xl.parse(sheet)
    # Set headers 
    df = df[1:]
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df[1:]
    list_of_dfs.append(df)
dfs = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, ignore_index=True)
dfs
```

However, if I try to add another sheet to be read, named 2022 by rearranging the range from 12:13 to 11:13, an overflow error is returned.

> 120 if 0 < value < 60 and epoch == WINDOWS_EPOCH:
> 121     day += 1
> --> 122 return epoch + datetime.timedelta(days=day) + diff
>
> OverflowError: date value out of range

Can someone please explain what the issue is and how do I bypass this error?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some data errors in the spreadsheet. You can use exceptions to temporality bypass some errors:

```
for sheet in xl.sheet_names[11:13]:
    try:
        df = xl.parse(sheet)
        # Set headers 
        df = df[1:]
        df.columns = df.iloc[0]
        df = df[1:]
        list_of_dfs.append(df)
    except:
        # Handle the error (e.g., skip the problematic sheet)
        print(f"Error reading sheet '{sheet}': Skipping...")
        continue
```